# Sub setting very large data frames in R efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, large-data, bigdata

So I have a data frame of 16 columns and ~17 million rows.

I would first like to do some `ddply` on the data frame and then look at the correlations between the different columns. What’s the best and most efficient way to achieve this? My current approach takes too long:

The data frame is `all_df` and column names are `A`, `B`, `C`, ..., `N`, `O`, `P`

```
avB <- ddply(all_df, c(“A”), summarise, NB_av=mean(B), NB_sd=sd(B))
avC <- ddply(all_df, c(“A”), summarise, NC_av=mean(C), NC_sd=sd(C))
avD <- ddply(all_df, c(“A”), summarise, ND_av=mean(D), ND_sd=sd(D))
avE <- ddply(all_df, c(“A”), summarise, NE_av=mean(E), NE_sd=sd(E))
avF <- ddply(all_df, c(“A”), summarise, NF_av=mean(F), NF_sd=sd(F))
avG <- ddply(all_df, c(“A”), summarise, NG_av=mean(G), NG_sd=sd(G))

summary_df <- avB
summary_df <- merge(summary_df, avC, by=c(“A”))
summary_df <- merge(summary_df, avD, by=c(“A”))
summary_df <- merge(summary_df, avE, by=c(“A”))
summary_df <- merge(summary_df, avF, by=c(“A”))
summary_df <- merge(summary_df, avG, by=c(“A”))

#quick look at the correlation
plot((summary_df[,c(2,4,6,8,10,12)]), gap=0)
```

So, as it is, I am resolving to doing a lot of these, averages, standard deviations etc in MySQL and then doing the final co-relation analyses in R. However, I don't find that very elegant.

Why do I use a data frame instead of a data table? Because I am reading a MySQL table in to R, and the syntax `dbGetQuery(con,"select * from mysql_table")` returns a data frame.

Comment: Then convert the data.frame to a data.table?

Comment: you want the mean and sd for all columns but 1?

Comment: You could try `dplyr` ie. `library(dplyr); all_df%>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd), B:G)`

Comment: @akrun if you could add this as an answer, possibly with some benchmarking, I would +1 :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
 all_df %>% 
       group_by(A) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(mean, sd), B:G)
```

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(all_df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))), by = A,
              .SDcols=LETTERS[2:6]][,var:= c('mean', 'sd')][]
```

NOTE: The results in the first form is in the wide format, while in the second we get the 'mean', 'sd' as alternative rows.

#### Benchmarks

```
 all_df1 <- all_df[rep(1:nrow(all_df), 1e5),]
 system.time(all_df1%>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd), B:G))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.189   0.000   0.189 

 DT1 <- as.data.table(all_df1)
 system.time(DT1[,lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))),
              A, .SDcols=LETTERS[2:6]][,var:= c('mean', 'sd')][])
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #0.232   0.002   0.235
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
m1 <- matrix(sample(1:20, 15*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=15)
set.seed(353)
all_df <- data.frame(sample(letters[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE), m1)
colnames(d1) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(d1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot akrun!

I built up on your answer and wrote up a complete example that also borrows from http://www.carlboettiger.info/2012/02/12/elegant-fast-data-manipulation-with-data-table.html It also shows how to call specific elements of the object resulting from the lapply.

```
#create a super large data frame:
grpsize = ceiling(1e7/26^2)

all_df1 <- data.frame(
            x=rep(LETTERS,each=26*grpsize),
            y=rep(letters,each=grpsize),
            v=runif(grpsize*26^2),
            v2=runif(grpsize*26^2),
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#to group by x and y andget length, mean from data frame
sumalldf <- ddply(all_df1, c("x","y"), summarise, ntotalldf = length(x), nmeanalldf = mean(v))

#convert to data.table
#more efficient way:
DT1 <- data.table(all_df1)

##less efficient way:   
DT2 <- as.data.table(all_df1)

#set keys on x,y columns
setkey(DT1,x,y) # for x only, use: setkey(DT,x)

#setting the key as above allows calling by column value : DT1["A"]
#if you don't setkey and attempt the above, you'll get an error warning you to set key

#take a look at DT1
print(head(DT1))
print(tail(DT1))

#now group data table by x,y and get mean and standard deviation for all other columns
sumalldt <- DT1[,lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))), by= list(x,y)][,var:= c('mean', 'sd')][]
#.SD stands for subset of data, in lay words it applies function (mean, sd) to all columns
#except the by columns

#take a look at this new object that holds the
#mean and standard deviation for all other columns
#after grouping by x,y
print(head(sumalldt))
print(tail(sumalldt)) 

#the keys for sumalldt get set by the 'by' components in lapply
print("some key, attributes etc for sumalldt")
print(key(sumalldt))
print(haskey(sumalldt))

#to get all values for x=B
#sumalldt["B"]

#to get all values for y=r
#sumalldt[list(unique(x),'r')]
#or
#sumalldt[y=="r"] # the former is more efficient

#say then you want to get the values only of x=B, y=r
print(paste("values for x=B, y=r"))
print(sumalldt[list('B','r')])

print("only the mean")
print(subset(sumalldt[list('B','r')],sumalldt[list('B','r')]$var=='mean')$v)
print(subset(sumalldt[list('B','r')],sumalldt[list('B','r')]$var=='mean')$v2)
```